# How to show that $ \inf \{ |x-a| : a \in A\} > 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, supremum-and-infimum

I was trying to prove something and part of it was to show that

$ \inf \{ |x-a| : a \in A\} > 0 $   where

$ A= \{ 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \dots, \frac{1}{n}, \dots \} $

It is clear that

$ \inf \{ |x-a| : a \in A\} \geq 0 $

I know it seems easy, however, I'm just stuck.

Comment: Even if you exclude $x\in A$, taking $x=0$ gives $0$ for the inf.

Comment: Your notation makes no sense to me. It is common to look for something like $\inf B$ where $B$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ but expressions like $\inf_{x\in\mathbb R}B(x)$ were $B(x)$ denotes a subset of $\mathbb R$ depending on $x$ have no familiar meaning to me.

Comment: @lulu note that we are looking for the infimum depending on x, so that would be just |a|

Comment: I had assumed that you were varying $a,x$.  If $a$ is fixed...what's the point of telling us the set it was chosen from?  How does one value of $a$ differ from any other?

Comment: Could define your notation? Whatever infimum you are taking, you can always define it to be the infimum of some fixed set, without the subscript $x\in\mathbb{R}$. For example, do you mean $\inf \{|x-a|:a\in A, x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ or $\inf\{|x-a|:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, where $a\in A$ is fixed?

Comment: To join the chorus that you need to clarify your notation, let me point out that the normal interpretation of $\inf_{x \in U} F(x)$ is $\inf \{F(x) : x \in U\}$. Thus your expression interprets to $\inf\{ \{|x - a| : a \in A\} : x \in \Bbb R\}$. That is, you are trying to take the infimum of a collection of sets. How are you comparing these sets to each other to define an infimum of them? These sets are not a chain of subsets, Nor in general is the intersection of a collection of the sets likely to be another such set.

Comment: @durianice, yes you are right I was confused, and I caused confusion. I apologize and I edited it, I hope now it's clear.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I tried to edit it, I hope it's clear now. I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: So now $x$ is constant and you want the distance from $x$ to the nearest value in $A$? For $x \le 0$ that will be $|x|$. For $x > 1$, it will be $x-1$. In $(0,1]$ the graph as a function of $x$ is a sequence of triangular peaks, getting smaller in size as $x$ decreases.

Comment: If $x\in A$, then one of those distances is zero, hence infimum is zero.

Comment: @PaulSinclair okay, so in order for that to be true $ x \notin A \cup \{0\}$

Comment: Yes, The infimum is $0$ exactly for all $x \in A\cup \{0\}$. Elsewhere it is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, $x\in A\cup\{0\}$ if and only if $\inf\{|x-a|:a\in A\}$.
More generally, for any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
the number $d(x,A):=\inf\{|x-a|:a\in A\}$ is called the distance between $x$ and $A$.
We have $d(x,A)=0$
iff
for any $n>0$,
there is $a_n\in A$ such that $|x-a_n|<\frac{1}{n}$
iff
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = x$ for some sequence $(a_n)\subseteq A$
iff
$x\in\overline{A}$.
In your case, $\overline{A}=A\cup \{0\}$.